# Coefficient $a_k$ of generating function

Tags: approximation, generating-functions, approximation-theory

Given a generating function $F(z)$, am I right to say that the coefficient $a_k$ of $[z^n]$ is computed by $\frac{F^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$ $(1)$.

Since we have the definition of $F(z)$ is:

$F(z) = \sum_{i > 0}{a_i*z^i}$

Differentiate $F(z)$ $i$ times then I have $(1)$.

However, do we have any approximation of $a_k$ when $k$ is large, since I don't think  compute differentiation of $F(z)$ 100 times is an easy work.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, that is Taylor's formula. It is likely that you have a specific function in mind. If you give it an specific effective method may exist. Otherwise, in general, ... derivative $100$ times ... Stating the problem in a general way doesn't necessarily make it more solvable.

Comment: @ABC so we don't have any general method to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't even know what "general" means. In general, how would one *give* a **general** generating function other than giving, somehow, the coefficients? If you can have the coefficients then you, in principle, **have** them. In particular you have the $100$-th. Now, if we leave the generalization madness, some especial generating functions happen to be simple enough elementary functions. Then interesting specific methods may exist.

Comment: @ABC I mean, given an arbitrary GF, do we have any other way to compute/approximate $[z^k]$ of it? The differentiation approach is not practical for large $k$.

Comment: The book [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html) by Flajolet and Sedgewick gives an overview of how such an approximation could be obtained in Chapter 4.